# Anding two numbers into a boolean?

Tags: vb6

Can somebody explain to me how ANDing two numbers results in a boolean here? Why does `j=3` return true but `j=2` return false?

```
dim jak as Boolean
dim i as Integer
dim j as Integer

i = 1
j = 3
jak = j And i
Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!" & jak)
```

Comment: vb6 yes. not c# or vb.net

Comment: This *has* to be VB.NET. There is no Console.WriteLine in VB 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [The Microsoft documentation on the `AND` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/and-operator). When the operands are numeric rather than boolean, `AND` performs a bitwise `AND`, rather than a strictly logical `AND` as it does when the operands are booleans.

```
1 =  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
2 =  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
3 =  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1

1 AND 2 = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 = FALSE, when converted to boolean
1 AND 3 = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 = TRUE, when converted to boolean
```

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't get this problem if you had Option Strict On. It would tell you that converting an integer to a boolean is a problem. But without it, VB converts everything to True except for 0 which is false.

```
    Console.WriteLine(CBool(-2)) ' True
    Console.WriteLine(CBool(-1)) ' True
    Console.WriteLine(CBool(0)) ' False
    Console.WriteLine(CBool(1)) ' True
    Console.WriteLine(CBool(2)) ' True
    Console.WriteLine(CBool(3)) ' True
```

3 And 1 = 1 which is then converted to True

Answer (score 0):

It is doing a bitwise-and of i and j and then converting to boolean - non-zero is true.

1 and 3 -> 01 and 11 binary -> 01 which is non-zero therefore true.

1 and 2 -> 01 and 10 binary -> 00 which is zero therefore false